# How to resize buttons in button array

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to resize the buttons in a button array I made, but I don't know how

Here's my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    final TableLayout container = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout5);

    Button btn[][] = new Button[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
             btn [i][j] = new Button(this);


             container.addView(btn[i][j],i);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by resizing button? You mean setting the size or change the size after setting it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know if you know, but this will create 100 buttons, anyway:
it can be done like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width_of_button , height_of_button);
    final TableLayout container = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout5);

    Button btn[][] = new Button[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
            btn [i][j] = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Button "+i+":"+j);   // if you need to trace which is which



            container.addView(btn[i][j],i,lp);// add button with specified dims

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [java.awt.Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html) class, which I'm assuming since I see no other specification here, you need to create a [java.awt.Dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) object to specify the size.

```
Dimension size=new Dimension(4,6); //where 4 is the width and 6 is the height, although odds are you will need something much bigger

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {     
         btn [i][j] = new Button(this);
         btn.setSize(size); //inherited from Component

         container.addView(btn[i][j],i);
    }
}
```

Change the values of the height and width as you see fit, should work.
You may also need to import java.awt.Dimension

Comment: Though to code is java, he is using Android which i don't thinlk has java.awt.Button

Answer (score 0):

You can resize button by modified its LayoutParams, like this:

```
  TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
  params.height = 40;
  params.width = 100;
  button.setLayoutParams(params);
```